# Recycler view items take its width and can continue with new row

Tags: android, user-interface

is there any way to make a design like this (image)

**EXPLANATION**: 
List of items where item take its width if screen widths are not fit so continue in next row.

Item(2) starts after the item(1) and **continues in the next row**.

Items will be **textviews**

[image]

**flexlayout** has limit if item will not fully fit it make it in another row

**Edit:**

**(Assume Case )**
assume I have two texts and want to display them 
for ex text1 = "Hello ", text2 = "Ahmed"
and screen width can fit 8 character 
so UI should be

Hello  A

hmed

**[Actual Case]**

[image]

here there are two texts , first with below background and second without this is final UI

Comment: Sorry @Mahmoud but your question is not specific... I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I have added screens with final UI

Comment: so you want هداي  on the first line? or هدا only ?

Comment: Text with background start in row and ends in new row, 
i want text to grow and continue in next row, also 
next text start where first one ends

Comment: You need to show your xml code so others can help

Comment: I am asking to make proper xml code (Currently i am using single TextView, but want more control over texts)

Comment: Use two seperate text views. Add (android:scrollHorizontally="false") attribute to each TextView in xml.

Answer (score 1):

A small example for assuming the case

```
input: Hello Ahmed

expected output :Hello A

hmed
```

You can store a list of strings into single string. Make text view height wrap content using Spanable string, you can have more control on text.

Comment: problem is, i can not determine end of first line, as it varies from text to another, from screen to another

Comment: @MahmoudMabrok I think u can combine the list of values into a single string  and set  height as wrap content

Comment: inital i think of this but i want to have more control on texts

Comment: U can use Scannable string for have more control on text

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding `android:scrollHorizontally="false"` to the `TextView` xml that is displaying the text.

```
<TextView
.
.
.
android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

Comment: could you  provide more details and explanation

Comment: Please edit your question and insert your xml code in the question

Comment: I am starting to design it